# VM Heap Tab missing in DDMS

Tags: android, memory-management

Going over this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) on memory analysis, and realized i don't have any  **VM Heap Tab**  in my DDMS tool. Searched all over the tool, not finding that. Am i missing some thing, can you please point me to the right place. Thanks for your help in advance

I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Window--->Show View--->Android--->Heap

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i dont see any window where the Heap Memory and allocated memory are displayed. I am expecting some screen like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iYqRtBzuPEw/Uzc9uqm3yyI/AAAAAAAAATY/RJQm-z0ySUI/s400/ddms-heap-usage.png)

Comment: Yes, in DDMS you can find it under 'Heap' tab. If you don't see this tab then add it as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks again for the response, but i see most of the items in Disabled state. Note: I had device tab displayed earlier, but i closed once, now i am unable to even reopen that

Comment: Most of the items will be in disabled state until you start debugging of your app and choose update heap option from DDMS. But did you try to open Window option and then choose Show View from submenu? And then did you try to add 'Heap' tab from displayed dialog?

Comment: When i had the device tab, i was able to choose update heap option, now i tried resetting the perspective, all i see is a blank screen

Comment: I will repeat once again :) Every tab in DDMS including 'Devices' tab can be added in following way - from the bar on top of the screen where you have menu options choose Window and then from submenu ShowView, a dialog will be displayed from which you can choose which tab you want to add. As simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the DDMS workspace preferences folder solved the issue. Preference is stored in %USERPROFILE%.android\monitor-workspace (e.g. C:\Users\my_user.android\monitor-workspace).

For Ubuntu users, you can find the file in

```
   home/my_user/.android/monitor-workspace.
```

Its a hidden file, so use **Ctrl + H** to view them.